# How do I write a custom fuction to work like dplyr with base r?

Tags: r

I need to write a custom function that accomplishes the following without using dplyr:

```
func <- function (dataframe, var1, var2, var3) {
  var1 <- enquo(var1)
  var2 <- enquo(var2)
  var3 <- enquo(var3)
  
  dataframe %>%
    group_by(!!var1, !!var2) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(!!var3))
}
```

I need a dataframe in the end result. How do I do this with base R and for loops?

Comment: Should the var1, var2, .. be quosure? i..e Please show a small reproducible example 'temp_var', 'spat_var' etc.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to rename the variables. var1, var 2 should be quosure.

Comment: why would you need for loops? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not opposed to passing the column names as character strings (quoted) then the stats::aggregate() function could work:

```
func <- function (dataframe, var1, var2, var3) {
  out <- aggregate(get(var3) ~ get(var1) + get(var2), dataframe, sum)
  names(out) <- c(var1, var2, "sum")
  return(out)
}

func(mtcars, "cyl", "am", "hp")

  cyl am  sum
1   4  0  254
2   6  0  461
3   8  0 2330
4   4  1  655
5   6  1  395
6   8  1  599
```

More generally, you could use a .group_vars argument that accepts a character vector of grouping variables like this:

```
func <- function (dataframe, .group_vars, var3) {
  out <- aggregate(as.formula(paste0(var3, "~ .")), 
                   dataframe[, c(.group_vars, var3)], sum)
  names(out)[ncol(out)] <- "sum"
  return(out)
}

func(mtcars, c("cyl", "am", "vs"), "hp")

  cyl am vs  sum
1   8  0  0 2330
2   4  1  0   91
3   6  1  0  395
4   8  1  0  599
5   4  0  1  254
6   6  0  1  461
7   4  1  1  564
```